What are the philosophical arguments for and against existential inertia?
Existential inertia is a concept that seems to have been coined by Edward Feser, a leading theistic philosopher, which he mentions in his paper here that relates to the Aristotelian proofs for god.
As per the paper,

The “existential inertia” thesis holds that, once in existence, the natural world tends to remain in existence without need of a divine conserving cause

What are the arguments for and against this concept?

Bonus:
I wonder if a more general
principle can be formulated that asks if something that exists and remains in existence needs a further explanation for the continuity of its existence over and above the lack of physical forces that would destroy its existence, whether or not one believes this explanation is theistic or not.

Existence doesn't need a further explanation qua existence itself in the same way as zero doesn't need a further explanation qua its nothingness nature when applied to books or pens. If a phenomenal non-existence occurs from a phenomenal existence, there could be in need of an explanation about a respective phenomenal destruction, like the perennial causal chain which is said to be observed from the phenomenal existence of cause and its subsequent phenomenal non-existence with a dependent arising of a new phenomenal existence. So equivalently how the chain is maintained like a physical one?...

If you want to read arguments for and against: visit his blog where he engages in flame wars against people who use his own (!) invented argument, existential inertia, against his own (!) defense of an Aristotelian (Thomistic) proof of God...  Go figure...

I'm not sure what the alternative is. Powers who must continuously maintain and operate reality or it will change or cease to exist? That sounds unreasonably tiring, not to mention boring, for those powers. One can certainly speculate that, but has anybody actually done so? This feels like it is a counter to an argument that is not being made.

there seems to be an answer to this question in this blog
https://zelluloza.ru/blogs/1852840-knigi-o-russkoy-filosofii/

"Existential inertia" is not any new concept, just a label slapped on old arguments against some proofs of theism, in particular metaphysical proofs of god (based on logic alone).
In antiquity this was about deism vs. theism, whether a creator god (a "prime mover" in causal chains) could just set the universe in motion and step back for a well-deserved holiday, or whether the universe required ongoing maintenance by a god present everywhere all the time.
So the parties involved are:

those who claim theism can be proven because all objects need some ongoing cause to exist all the time (in antiquity and the middle ages, like Thomas Aquinas and other Christian church philosophers)
Those who think that instead (some) objects can, once created, independently continue to exist without an outer cause helping them to continue existing (Also in antiquity and the middle ages, like Aristotle). This is now labelled "Existential inertia thesis".
Edward Feser (and others) who published articles the previous group is wrong about Existential Inertia being possible, thus theism proofs being correct (2011 and later)
Joe Schmid and others who respond that "Existential inertia thesis" is not disproven by Feser, such that it is possible and those proofs of theism insufficient (though other proofs remain untouched)

The actual arguments are technical and not new, relying on interpretation of arguments since antiquity. Even trying to summarize the back and forth between these authors a response would be too long for this site. Basically a bunch of modern philosophers beating a dead horse trying to justify their salaries by writing about something already overly discussed, hoping to draw attention to themselves (which to some degree is their job description).

“a bunch of modern philosophers beating a dead horse trying to justify their salaries by writing about something already overly discussed.” this is arguably almost all of philosophy and probably explains why funding in philosophy is piss poor

One way of seeing this is through Freudian psychology, which suggests the existence of a death drive (Thanatos), which results in people indulging in self-destructive behaviors or simply passivity, because continuing living requires too much effort (either physical, or in terms of the questions/problems that one has to resolve.) That is, in terms of the Q. - continuing existence itself is a burden.

I'd ague why not go one moment earlier to T=0 and say existence exists by necessity, it cannot "not exist", so it makes this whole idea of "What keeps the world going?" irrelevant. It's answering a question that we don't really  have to answer. E.g. Why is a circle so round? What keeps it round?
It's not even clear that absolute/total nothingness is even metaphysically coherent.
Even if we grant that the coherence of the idea of the set of domains of logical discourse is the empty set, we then question whether it is metaphysically possible - can nothigness survive when somethingness is a possibility?
The argument that existence exists necessarily mirrors Thomistic arguments for God's necessary existence. Existence's essence is its existence. It's just that instead of finding being/mind at T=0 we find an initial state (which we think was extremely low entropy and hence almost perfectly uniform and simple).
In fact, the description of the big bang singularity sounds an awful lot like the Thomistic view of God, sans it being a being/mind.
